# How are these two proofs should differ?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Here is a question:

Let $f$ be integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu.$ Show that $\int_{E}f d\mu = 0$ for every measurable subset $E$ of $X$ if and only if $f = 0$ a.e. on $X.$

And the last part of this proposition is similar to the previous question (but not exactly the same):

> [image]

And I know that the last part of this proposition can be proved as follows:

[image]

**My Question is:**

In the first question, we do not have the assumption that $f$ is nonnegative, so how can modify the proof in the last part of the proposition to include the negative part of $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is real, 
$$\{f\neq 0\}=\{f>0\}\cup\{f<0\}=\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f\geq \frac{1}{n}\}\Big)\cup\Big(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\{f\leq -\frac{1}{n}\})$$
and so if it is not the case that $f=0$ a.e. then one of the sets in the union must have positive measure, and you can consider the integral of $f$ over this set.

If $f$ is complex-valued then you can consider the real and imaginary parts of $f$ separately and use the above.

Comment: I have tried to do what you said but I failed as $\int_{E} f d\mu$ could be zero even though one of the sets in the union have positive measure and another set in the union have the same value of measure but with negative sign ...... or the negative sign measure is not allowed?

Comment: Yes, my assumption was that $\mu$ is a positive measure.