# How the solution of these two questions will differ?(Royden and Fitzpatrick "Real analysis" 4th edition)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I know the proof of this question:

Let $f$ be a nonnegative bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure $E$. Assume $\int_{E} f = 0.$ Show that $f = 0$ a.e. on $E.$

**Here it is.**

Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on a set of finite measure $E.$Then by $\textbf{Theorem 4 on page 74}$, $f$ is integrable over $E.$\

Also, By $\textbf{page 54 definition of a.e.}$, we know that a property is said to hold almost everywhere (abbreviated a.e.) on a measurable set $E$ provided it holds on $E \setminus E_{0}$, where $E_{0}$ is a subset of $E$ for which $m(E_{0}) = 0.$\

Now, since $f$ is nonnegative, so $f$ can not take negative values and we have only 2 sets:

Define
$$A :=\{ x\in E: f(x)=0 \}$$ and $$B:=\{x\in E: f(x)>0\}.$$
Then 
$$\int_E f = \int_A f + \int_B f = \int_B f = 0.$$\
because $f(x) = 0$ on $A$ and using $\textbf{page 76 corollary 6,}$ as $E = A \cup B$ and the last equality because  we have an assumption of  $ \int_{E}f = 0.$\

Since $f$ is positive on $B,$ in order for $\int_B f=0,$ one must have $m(B)=0,$ that is, Lebesgue measure of $B$ must be zero.\

\textbf{Now to show that $m(B)=0.$}\

Since $B$ is measurable, we can write it as a countable union of disjoint measurable sets. For example 
 $B = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n$ where $$B_n = \{x \in E:f(x)\ge 1/n\}.$$

Now it is enough to prove that the measure of each of the sets in the union is zero. Let there be a natural number $N$ such that $$m( \{x \in E:f(x)\ge 1/N\}) = \lambda (\neq 0).$$

Now, $Let E_{1} = \{x \in E :f(x)\ge 1/N \}, $ Let $E_{2} = \{x \in E :f(x)\leq 1/N \}$, thus $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ are measurable disjoint sets and $E = E_{1} \cup E_{2}.$ therefore $$ \int_{E}f = \int_{E_{1}}f + \int_{E_{2}}f.$$\

But $\int_{E_{1}}f > (1/N) m({E_{1})$, because $f(x)\ge 1/N$ on  $E_{1}.$ But $m({E_{1}) = \lambda ,$ therefore  $\int_{E_{1}}f = (\lambda / N) > 0.$ Consequently  $\int_{E} f > 0,$ which contradicts the hypothesis that $\int_{E} f = 0.$\

Hence, $m(B):=\{x\in E: f(x)>0\} = 0$ therefore $f = 0$ a.e on $E$.

**But I do not know how to prove this question:**

Let $f$ be integrable over $X$ with respect to $\mu.$ Show that $\int_{E}f d\mu = 0$ for every measurable subset $E$ of $X$ if and only if $f = 0$ a.e. on $X.$

I got a hint here [How are these two proofs should differ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3516684/how-are-these-two-proofs-should-differ)  but still I do not know how to apply it.

**My confusion is:**

$\int_{E}fd\mu $ could be zero even though one of the sets in the union mentioned in the hint have positive measure and another set in the same union have the same value of measure but with negative sign ...... or the negative sign measure is not allowed?

I am confused about how to implement the hint, could anyone help me in doing so please?

Comment: This question is about positive measures. The measure of a set cannot be negative.

Comment: Ok I see now @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I mean that if $f=1$ and $f=-1$ on the set B of measure say 2, we will get 0 in the integration ..... correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\neq 0$ on $E$ with $\mu E>0$, let $E_+=\{x\in E:f(x)>0\},\, E_- =\{x\in E: f(x)<0\}$. Then $E$ is the disjoint union of $E_+$ and $E_-$, so one of which has positive measure.

Comment: I know this but I do not know how to continue? I need the detailed steps

Comment: $f$ is alredy given to be $\geq 0$. OP is wondering if  a set can have negative measure.

Comment: The problem in the second question that I want to solve that my $f$ is just integrable, so it can take negative values ..... shall I modify the proof of the first problem to include $f<0$ ? if so hoe can I be sure that there is not f>0 so that the sum of their integrals is zero?